# How to get multiple regex matches in Java?

Tags: java, regex, multiple-matches

How can I find all substrings that match a regex in Java? (Similar to [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) in .Net)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a Matcher and use `find()` to position it on the next match.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a code sample:

```
int countMatches(Pattern pattern, String str) {
  int matches = 0;
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  while (matcher.find())
    matches++;
  return matches;
}
```