# Jenkins groovy postbuild - parsing console log for pattern but only save the last matched line

Tags: parsing, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to parse the JMeter log in the Jenkins console with groovy postbuild. But I want the last 
line only, since that gives the average req/sec for all the connections.
(Example: summary =      2 in     1s =    3.0/s Avg:   107 Min:    56 Max:   159 Err:     0 (0.00%))

But my current groovy postbuild script just picks the first hit in the console.
What I want is the same as what I would get if the console searched was started from the end. (reverse) I.e. the last match in the console.

Current:

def summary_matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*summary = (.*)(.Err:)(.*)\$")

manager.addShortText(summary_matcher.group(1)[0..-1] + .......)

And I cannot improve the summary pattern to just pick the final line...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looping the result or something similar: 
[How to get multiple regex matches in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266943/how-to-get-multiple-regex-matches-in-java)

Api doc for Matcher:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

[Find the last match with Java regex matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417435/find-the-last-match-with-java-regex-matcher)